# Matlab - Frame lines in Hough Transform

Tags: matlab, transform, hough-transform

I'm implementing Hough-Radon transform in Matlab to detect some patterns (stright lines mostly). I've already implemented it, but the problem is that it also detects the "frame" as a line (see picture).

[image]

The code to implement this is basically:

```
[H,T,R] = hough(BW,'RhoResolution',0.6,'Theta',-90:0.5:89.5);
P  = houghpeaks(H,20,'threshold', ceil(0.1*max(H(:))));
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap', 15,'MinLength',50);
```

Where lines is a struct composed by the fields:

- Starting point.
- Ending point.
- Angle Tetha
- Distance Rho

Is there anything I could do to get rid of the four frame lines?

Edit:

The original picture before perform the Hough transform is:

[image]

Comment: Never seen this before. Are you sure those are not in `BW`? In any case, you can remove them from `P` because you know the parameters of these 4 lines.

Comment: I've updated the question with the original picture before the Hough Transofrm. To remove them by the angle is impossible because the desired line has the same angle. And the points each time are diferent so cannot be removed by that way. any other idea?

Comment: that's not the BW image because it's not binary. How do you binarize it?

Comment: `P` contains both angle and distance for each line. You can find out what angle and distance correspond to these lines and remove them. Why do you say the points are different each time? What points? In the Hough space? Is it random???

Comment: Regarding what I said about the points (which is the starting and ending point of each line), I have several images similar to that (but not equal), so each time I perform the hough transform and I got the lines, the "frame" lines are slighlty diferent. For example the first time starts in the position (1,1) and the next time in the (2,4). So I cannot filter them by removing an specific position because each time is diferent (and could be posible that the true line I want to detect is very near the frame).

Comment: Before performe the Hough Transform I do: F = getframe; I = rgb2gray(frame2im(F)); and BW = edge(I,'canny');     Where Getframe obtains the frame of the second image posted above.

Comment: ah, there it is. Don't use Canny. It seems to detect edges at the image boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your preprocessing. Look at the binary image `BW` that you put into `hough`: it has those lines in it.

I recommend that you replace your binarization with something like this:

```
BW = imbinarize(I, 128);
BW = bwmorph(BW,'skel');
```

Comment: With this I almost got it. The vertical lines have disapeared, but the horitzontal (frame lines) are still present. I've also checked it with n=inf.

Comment: @Pep: yes, there are some lines along the outside of the image, I thought they were too subtle for Otsu to pick them up. But maybe you need to manually find a better threshold. I have updated the answer with a manual threshold (128). Tweak this value until you only see the line of interest in your BW image.

Comment: According to Matlab help, the threshold should be between 0 and 1, isn't?

Comment: No, I think it is just the value at which you want to threshold. I assumed your input is in the 0-255 range. You can also just do `BW=I>128`.

Comment: I finally have it! I've used   imbinarize(I, 'adaptive', 'Sensitivity', 0.01);  and I get only the central line, without the "frame". Thanks a lot!